# A book about a military helicopter pilot who uses portals

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for this book I read 5 to 6 years ago about a military helicopter pilot who somehow gets the power to control portals and he travels through a portal to find out that they lead to an alien planet that the military is siphoning resources from.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can add anymore details.

Comment: I'm wondering if he just means "paintings".

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I was questioning where portraits came from at all.  But Edlothiad wasn't even the person who inserted that.  Took the reference out.

Comment: Nor was Ali... 
@TimSparrow: Please don't add details to the questions that the original person did not.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I assumed it was an honest mistake/misreading with the 2 portals in the sentence.  Either that or [bad autocorrecting](http://www.damnyouautocorrect.com/).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, sorry, misread the original sentence

Comment: @TimSparrow: It's alright. :) More mild chiding than anything else. I've done it before myself.

Answer (score 4):

Had to dig a bit but I found it. It's called 'Control Point(Shadow Ops #1)'
Thanks everyone!

Comment: You can accept your own answer 48 hours after asking the question.